# Android - mount: Read-only file system

Tags: android, system, root, tablet, mount

Someone can help me? I have rooted tablet, but can't modify to read/write:

```
root@android:/# mount -o rw, remount /dev/block/system
mount: Read-only file system
```

while from adb:

```
C:\SDK\sdk\platform-tools\adb remount
remount succeeded
```

but the filesystem is r/o yet. I can't change anything in /system and remount is not working. No way how to get it r/w. Do you know somebody what is setting the /system to read only? Why it is blocked when I'm root and remounting has run.

Comment: This is clearly off-topic here and should most likely go to android.SE site.  However to help you, try removing the space between `rw,` and `remount` and change the device to just `/system` (or a proper block device).  This should work: `mount -o rw,remount /system`

Comment: Hi Aleks, I've tried rw,remount, but the same response from system. There must be something what is holding the r/o status of /system directory. I don't know unix at all, maybe there is some process which is checking the status and don't let me to change the r/w status. I'm desparate, because all of threads of forums are helping in way "mount -o etc...". Nowhere is some solution after this step doesnt work.

Comment: Make sure to use the correct block device number (e.g. `/dev/block/mtdblock0`).  Use `mount` command to see the list of devices with their mounting points. Other than that, depending on your handset, there may be some protection in place to prevent you doing that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't figured it out, I gave up. It's finding a needle in a haystack. I didn't found any way how to change it, nobody gave applicable workaround. I have this problem on tablet, I don't bother now.

Comment: I have the same problem, could you gave me more detail about your kernel and the tablet you're using ?

Comment: Use this command and try : mount -o rw,remount -t ext4 /system